# How to use instances index in the Xpath expressions?

Tags: karate

I am trying to set the xml value using a simple xPath expression with the instance count.

My XML:

```
 <ebm:ProcessCustomerPaymentBasketTotal>
<ebm:header>
  <ebm:creationDateTime>2019-07-16T05:20:11.446+01:00</ebm:creationDateTime>
  <ebm:serviceID>19da587a352911e985ddb2f6c8a3ba75</ebm:serviceID>
  <ebm:messageID>PPR SERVICE TEST 2019-07-16T23:25:03</ebm:messageID>
  <ebm:languageCode>EN</ebm:languageCode>
  <ebm:versionID>2.0.0</ebm:versionID>
   </ebm:header>
  <ebm:header>
  <ebm:creationDateTime>2019-07-16T05:20:11.461+01:00</ebm:creationDateTime>
  <ebm:serviceID>a38d367635f811e9b9b59ddfef421b03</ebm:serviceID>
  <ebm:messageID>PPR SERVICE TEST</ebm:messageID>
  <ebm:languageCode>EN</ebm:languageCode>
  <ebm:versionID>2.0.0</ebm:versionID>
 </ebm:header>
  </ebm:ProcessCustomerPaymentBasketTotal>
```

Feature file: (Combinations I tried)

```
* set xmlMessage //messageID[2] = '123456' 
* set xmlMessage (//messageID)[2] = '123456'
```

Both the above combinations didn't work and fulfil my purpose. Could you please suggest any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the xpath wrong:

```
* set xmlMessage //header[2]/messageID = '123456'
```

Comment: Thank you!!. Is there any way to specify the instances for the whole XPath like  (//header/messageID)[2].  Just trying to use  traditional XPath expressions

Comment: Yes. Could you please clarify the above question?

Comment: @DeepakPrabhu answer is no. feel free to contribute a fix if you think it is a problem

Comment: Hi @Peter. This framework has enormously helped our organisation in performing API automation.  Though we had karate Netty for JMS, we had some specific requirement for this asynchronous protocol. so wrote some customised java functions and integrated using Java Interop.  Could you please have a glance at this slides and provide me the feedback which would enormously help me  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RcA-uTWdlTa53OFGcQ3pn8o_5h0apfqE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you don't want to corrupt the thread, sir! you can mail me to deepakprabhu.cts@gmail.com

Comment: @DeepakPrabhu can't look at it in detail - but sounds like java interop is working well for you